# Can't resume from suspend in Nvidia GPU mode

Tags: graphic-drivers, suspend

So, the problem is that my laptop (Acer Extensa 2510G) can't resume from suspend while I'm using the NVIDIA GPU mode.

When I try to wake the system it shows me a little terminal cursor on a black screen, but nothing happens then. I can briefly switch to another tty but if I try to login the system hangs so I need to do the hard reboot.

I use the 340.93 driver from nvidia-340-updates, the kernel version is 3.19.0-31.

When I'm using the Intel mode the problem doesn't occur.
Thanks in advance